# Vanishing the Lie derivative of a volume element

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, vector-fields

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $X=(-y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\omega=Vdx\wedge dy$ be a smooth volume element in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $L_X\omega=0$ if and only if $V(x,y)$ depends only on $x^2+y^2$.

Intuitively I know why is this true: Integral curves of $X$ are actually circles around origin and $L_X\omega=0$ means that $\omega$ is constant on integral curves so $V$ is a constant multiple of $x^2+y^2$. Actually I can prove that $\Phi_t(\omega)=\omega$ for all possible $t$ where $\Phi$ is the flow of $X$.

I have problem writing down the proof since I do not know how to find the flow of $X$ and finish the proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you already know the integral curves, you just need to figure out how the parameter $t$ works (hint: polar coordinates).

Comment: @user10354138 When I try to compute the pullback of $\Phi_t$ everything gets too complicated.

Comment: If you know that the integral curves are circles, then you certainly should have a good guess what the flow is. But you should be able to solve the system $\dot x=-y$, $\dot y=x$ by elementary means. You meant to write $\Phi_t^*\omega$?